# How do I teach Emacs to re-wrap /* */ comments?

Tags: comment, wrapping

Is there an existing function, and if not how would I write one, that turns this:

```
/* asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd  */
/* asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd */
/* asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd  asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd */
/* asdasdasd asdasdasd */
/* asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd */
```

into this?

```
/* asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd */
/* asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd */
/* asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd */
```

That function should also work for other languages with multi-line comments, like tuareg-mode with `(* … *)`.  I'd like to achieve the same behavior as M-q for line comments (which properly wraps and adjusts comment markers like `//`.

Comment: You can loop over `forward-comment` (both forwards and backwards) to establish the bounds of the commented region, then `uncomment-region`, `fill-region`, `comment-region` to reformat it.

Comment: @phils That sounds pretty good, though a bit heavy-weight (note to self: I'd also have to change the fill-column to make sure that the added `/*` and `*/` don't make the text too long).  I wonder if this could be achieved with a combination of fill-prefix and comment-start and…

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be able to modify `comment-style` and perhaps `comment-styles` to suit your needs, and reformat with `comment-region` afterwards.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? AFAIK comment-region doesn't reflow comments.